# After dynamically export files, typescript cannot find module [ File '/index.tsx' is not a module. ts(2306) ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I tried to dynamically export all my components in my project. But tsl does not allow me to pass and throw the error message `File '/src/components/index.tsx' is not a module. ts(2306)`

How can I prevent this error and make it understand that these are the dynamic export modules?

This is my **folder structure**

```
src
|_ components
|  |
|  |_ index.tsx
|  
|_ index.tsx
```

In **/src/components/index.tsx**, I tried to **dynamically export** all the components

```
const cache: any = {};
function getAllComponents() {
  req.keys().forEach((key) => {
    if (!(/^\.\/index.tsx$/.test(key))) {
      const regex = /^\.\/([^\/]+)[\/].+/;
      const found = key.match(regex)[1];
      const newKey = found.split('-')
                        .map(name => name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase())
                        .join('');
      cache[newKey] = req(key).default;
    }
  });
  return { ...cache, __esModule: true };
}

module.exports = getAllComponents();
```

In **/src/index.tsx**, I tried to export all from components folder.

```
export * from './components/index';
```

It throws an error on this line `export * from './components/index` in **/src/index.tsx**.
**Error message:** File '/src/components/index.tsx' is not a module. ts(2306)

Comment: you have to export in source file ie  /src/components/index.tsx and import in /src/index.tsx .

Comment: Hi Ramkumar P, Thanks for your reply. As I have written in the post, I already exported all my components dynamically in /src/components/index.tsx. Typescript does not understand dynamic export patterns right now according to github issue posted in here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32046#issuecomment-506051884